# SqlDataReader and SelectedItem for data type Time in Combobox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have this code which should read data type Time and then SelectItem,but it doesn't select Item.

This is how I fill it:

```
void vypl_comboboxy()
{
   spojeni.Open();
   var cb1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT odjezd FROM stanice WHERE akce='"
                            + selectrowid+ "' ORDER BY odjezd ASC", spojeni);

   SqlDataReader dr1 = cb1.ExecuteReader();

   while (dr1.Read())
   {
       comboBox1.Items.Add(dr1["odjezd"]);
   }

   dr1.Close();
   dr1.Dispose();
}
```

This is how I select item at the moment but the combobox stays empty. How should I improve my code?

```
SqlCommand novyprikaz = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM klient WHERE ID_K=" + selectrowid, spojeni);
spojeni.Open();

SqlDataReader precti = novyprikaz.ExecuteReader();

if (precti.Read())
{
   comboBox1.SelectedItem = precti.GetTimeSpan(16).ToString();
}
```

Comment: ***Please***: since you're using Microsoft's **SQL Server**, label your questions with a `sql-server` tag! Just `sql` isn't enough - SQL is just the query language that's used by many database systems. Please be precise!

Comment: Which item number do you want to select? first last or any specific. In your current code it will update selected item on every read from database.

Comment: I would like to select Item "where ID_K=selectrowid" SelectedItem works fine for other data types like char or varchar, but there is problém wih data type TIME in SQL DB maybe?

Comment: `TIME` from MS SQL is converted to `DateTime` in C#. I suppose, that you have difference in seconds/milliseconds in your `DateTime` values. Look at them more attentively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the item is already in the combo box, use:

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.FindString(precti.GetTimeSpan(16).ToString());
```

Comment: Item is already in the combobox but when I load form I would like to select the one which is in the table in SQL DB, but it doesn't select that item even with your code.

Comment: What is at ordinal 16 in the returned table from "SELECT * FROM klient.."? Is it the same set of data that you've filled the combobox with?

Comment: Additionally you could try:
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.FindString(precti.GetTimeSpan(16).ToString());

Comment: Yes 16 is column index for column "odjezd" and I do use it for filling and reading. But when reading the combobox is filled but the Item isn't selected.

Comment: This answer sounds like `if (someBool.ToString().ToLower() == "true")`.

Comment: comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.FindString(precti.GetTimeSpan(16).ToString()); Worked well, thanks so much!

Comment: @MarekŠíp: *do not* search items in list controls by their string representation, ever. This is a direct way to hell.

Comment: @Dennis Why do you think so? I'm begginer in c#/sql. Would you explain it for me please?

Comment: Updated answer to what helped you - that first one I put was a bit dodgy. Also i'm not sure about the searching list controls for strings either, explanation/link would be great!

Comment: Code sample, provided in this answer, makes assumption, that value format being used is the same both for `ComboBox` and for `ToString` method. Any uncoordinated interference in value formatting (e.g., look at `ComboBox.Format` event) will break your code. Search for **data**, do not search for its string representation.

Comment: To better explain what am I talking about. Add `ComboBox.Format` handler for your control. Put this line into handler's body: `e.Value = ((DateTime)e.ListItem).ToLongDateString();`.